# Replace pandas column values based on another DF

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a sample DF:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,20,size=(6, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
sample_df["A_cat"] = ["ind","sa","sa","sa","ind","ind"]
sample_df["B_cat"] = ["sa","ind","ind","sa","sa","sa"]
sample_df
```

OP:

```
    A   B   A_cat   B_cat
0   12  8   ind     sa
1   12  11  sa      ind
2   7   19  sa      ind
3   5   11  sa      sa
4   11  7   ind     sa
5   6   18  ind     sa
```

I have another sample DF 2 for which I am trying to replace the column values based on a condition:

```
sample_df2 = pd.DataFrame()
sample_df2["A_cat"] = ["sa","ind","ind","sa","sa","ind"]
sample_df2["B_cat"] = ["ind","sa","sa","ind","sa","sa"]
sample_df2
```

OP:

```
    A_cat   B_cat
0   sa     ind
1   ind    sa
2   ind    sa
3   sa     ind
4   sa     sa
5   ind    sa
```

Condition:

```
The value in sample_df2 should be replaced by taking a groupby mean of that value in sample_df.
```

For example, `sample_df2(0,A_cat) = sa` which should be replaced by `sample_df.groupby(["A_cat"])["A"].mean() for group value sa`

sample OP of column `A_cat` in `sample_df2` after conversion will be:

```
sample_df2["A_cat"] = [8.0000,9.666667,9.666667,8.000,8.000,9.666667]
```

I have done the long for loop solution for this, any suggestions for pandas approach would be great!

Comment: added sample expected output.

Comment: Are you sure the sample output is correct, and the values are not switched (i.e. 9.66 where 8 should be and vice versa)?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Oh yea!! my bad. you are right.

Comment: I changed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code and compare the elapsed time

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
categorical_cols = [col for col in df1.columns if len(col.split('_')) > 1]
numerical_cols = df1[df1.columns.difference(categorical_cols)].columns
unique_groups = df1['A_cat'].unique().tolist() # returns [ind, sa]

for cat, num in zip(categorical_cols, numerical_cols):
    for group in unique_groups:
        df2.loc[df2[cat] == group, cat] = df1.groupby(cat)[num].mean().loc[group]

print("Elapsed time:", time.time() - start)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit clunky, but it works:

The actual calculations are done once:

```
category_value_means = sample_df2.apply(
    lambda column: sample_df.groupby(column.name)[column.name.split('_')[0]].mean())
```

whose output is:

```
    A_cat       B_cat
ind 9.666667    15
sa  8.000000    11
```

Afterwards, all is needed is some "lookup":

```
sample_df2.apply(lambda column: column.apply(lambda value: category_value_means[column.name][value]))
```

the output is:

```
    A_cat   B_cat
0   8.000000    15
1   9.666667    11
2   9.666667    11
3   8.000000    15
4   8.000000    11
5   9.666667    11
```

Comment: This is great! But its taking a long time for a huge DF any suggestions on how to speed it up?

Comment: Actually, there is. I just realized I have some major redundancy there. I've edited it accordingly.